# Spring Boot OAuth2 Role based Authorization Implementation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am stuck at the implementation at very initial steps. I have not shared any code below because I am confused about which method to choose for implementation.

I have the following requirements:

1. Given pair of `client_id` and client_secret to my Authorization Server endpoint (consider I hit Authorization endpoint from Postman), it should return an access token to access my APIs residing in Resource Server
2. Also I have an Angular based web application which will be logged in with Organization Credentials with certain roles like 'ADMIN', 'USER' based on which I need to restrict the API access from Web Application

After reading many articles on different oauth grant types, I came to understand that for the first requirement it is better to use clinet_credentials grant type as it does not require User authentication.
But I have Spring Security dependency which by default checks and authenticates the user. How do I achieve my first requirement without user authentication?

But whereas in my second requirement, Employees Database is managed by the organization. With the organization credentials, I need to authenticate and based on the logged-in user's role, I have to perform role management wherein Web User Interface I would like to hide few UI components and restrict few API access in the Server

What should be the implementation method that I should approach for this and what is the grant_type that has to be used in this case?

Is it mandatory to use both of the following dependencies? Are they independent / dependent of each other in any way?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The reason I am asking is that because of Spring Security only, I am forced to authenticate with a User and password whereas in my first requirement I would like to give only the client id and client secret with client credentials grant type.

Kindly share any useful links that will be related to my design or any sample code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to unravel in this question. Firstly, the `spring-security-oauth2` module has been deprecated and there is support for securing spring-boot apps via OAuth2 tokens in spring-security 5.

For your case #1, you are right to use the client_credentials grant type and I think you fully understand this flow.

For your case #2, an Angular application is just JavaScript code and it cannot securely store a client secret. So it's preferable to use the `authorization_code` grant type. This flow is described in the [OAuth 2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) and goes like this:

- Your Angular client sends a request to the `/authorize` endpoint of your authorization server. This request includes the `client_id` and a `redirect_uri` (usually a callback to the domain where your Angular UI is hosted).
- The authorization server will authenticate the user by redirecting the browser to an "Identity Provider", which will usually just show the user a login screen asking for user/pass. You can use identity providers like Facebook or Google or write your own following a standard like OIDC or SAML. Please check with your auth server how to integrate with various identity providers.
- Once authenticated, the auth server will issue a time-sensitive, 1 time use only "code" that will be sent back to the original `redirect_uri` that was submitted in the first step.
- This "code" is then sent by your Angular client to the auth server by calling the `/token` endpoint with the `client_id`, `redirect_uri`, `grant_type=authorization_code` and `code`.
- The auth server will validate the request details redirects the browser back to the `redirect_uri` along with the access token that is generated.

Once you have properly configured your auth server and identity provider, you can then secure your resource server via spring security 5 by looking at the official [spring-security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver).

Comment: Firstly, Is it possible to use more than one grant type in an application. I am confused that if I use Authorization code grant type, will my postman request not require authentication whereas in postman I want it to be a plain client credentials without user authentication as I do not manage the users database

Comment: Secondly, if I keep it as client credentials, how do I restrict few APIs access in postman for USER roles. I am pretty much confused on how to implement this scenario

Comment: In OAuth2, there is a concept of "clients". I'm not sure what auth server you are using, but you should be able to create "clients" and decide which grants you want to support. Your client can support client_credentials and authorization_code grants simultaneously. You can use the client_credentials grant from Postman using the auth server's `token` endpoint and the client_id/client_secret and the authorization_code grant for your users in your app using the `authorize` endpoint for the code. You cannot use the authorization_code grant from Postman.

Comment: Your auth server will define the user roles and the mapping between roles and "scopes". Clients and users can both request specific "scopes" using their respective grants. When the auth server issues the token, the scopes will be in the JWT token so you can use these for the authorization aspect of your app. You will have to use a JWT library to validate and decode the token. You will need a verification key to validate the digital signature of the JWT token and guarantee it's authenticity, which provides the authentication aspect of your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed explanation. I will try this way and let you know if any further queries. Once again, Thank you very very much.